# How to select latest order based on suffix in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table `Transactions` that has a column `OrderNumbers`. In this columns I have values for each order in format as:

```
OrderNumber
-----------
0001
0002
0003
0003-1
0004
0005
0006
0006-1
0006-2
0007
0008
0009
0010
0010-1
0011
0011-1
0011-2
0011-3
0012
```

Some of the orders being canceled and recreated. Which is where I have -1 and -2. The -2 would be the latest one and this can go up to -3,-4 and even -5 times to be recreated.

What I need to do is select query that will give me the data with all latest order which would look like this:

```
OrderNumber
------------
0001
0002
0003-1
0004
0005
0006-2
0007
0008
0009
0010-1
0011-3
0012
```

I know if I use:

```
select * 
from Transactions 
where OrderNumber not like '%-%'
```

I will exclude all orders with "-" in it. But how do I modify this to not exclude the latest order?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(OrderNumber, '-', 1)
                               ORDER BY CASE WHEN LOCATE('-', OrderNumber)
                                        THEN 0 + SUBSTRING_INDEX(OrderNumber, '-', -1)
                                        ELSE 0 
                                        END DESC ) rn
    FROM Transactions 
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

MySQL 8+ needed. Safe for multiple-digit version number.

For version 5.x use ROW_NUMBER() emulation (with UDV) or subquery with aggregation.

Comment: Thank you Akina, i have 5.6 so i will have to figure out second option.